# How can I create a new dataframe with only the species that are present in multiple depths?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a large number of species abundance samples taken at different depths. The data is arranged like:

```
df1 <- data.frame(sample = c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e','f','g','h','i'),
                  depth = c(10,20,30,10,20,30,10,20,30),
                  sp1 = c(1,0,0,2,0,0,5,0,0),
                  sp2 = c(1,4,6,5,3,1,5,6,4),
                  sp3 = c(0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0),
                  sp4 = c(1,0,5,4,3,7,8,4,1))
```

where the columns after sample and depth are indivdual species. I basically want to select only the species present in more than one depth and create a new dataframe looking at just these, like this:

```
df2 <- data.frame(sample = c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e','f','g','h','i'),
                  depth = c(10,20,30,10,20,30,10,20,30),
                  sp2 = c(1,4,6,5,3,1,5,6,4),
                  sp4 = c(1,0,5,4,3,7,8,4,1))
```

Any help would be much appreciated :)

Comment: when I run the code I get a dataframe with 15 observations of 12 variables which is what I was expecting: first column sample, second depth, remaining 10 different 'species' (X1-10) - does this make sense? That's what my real dataframe looks like, just much bigger and loads more zeros

Comment: I think in your example data, all species are present in more than one depth? And if you want to make reproducible example data using `sample()` you need to use `set.seed()`.

Comment: So your expected output is just your input data. How could you check whether an answer is correct or not? You should elaborate am example where some species meet your rule and some do not.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand - in my real dataset there are a lot more zeros so there are some species only present in one depth, I'm just not sure how to produce example data like that so I've made something similar. Do I just put set.seed(1) at the start of the script?

Comment: The only way I would know is to make an example dataset from scratch

Comment: This is not clear to me. Can you please (1) make your sample data reproducible by using a fixed random seed (using `set.seed()`, see neilfws's comment), and then (2) provide your expected output **matching your sample input data**. That will help us understand what you're trying to do and we can offer a solution.

Comment: Hi everyone - I've edited the example code, hopefully it makes more sense now? Thanks again for the help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```r
library(dplyr)

df1 %>%
  select(1:2, starts_with('sp') & where(~ n_distinct(df1$depth[.x != 0]) > 1))

#   sample depth sp2 sp4
# 1      a    10   1   1
# 2      b    20   4   0
# 3      c    30   6   5
# 4      d    10   5   4
# 5      e    20   3   3
# 6      f    30   1   7
# 7      g    10   5   8
# 8      h    20   6   4
# 9      i    30   4   1
```